# How to disable swipe up/down javascript code in https://github.com/marcandre/detect_swipe for iPhone

Tags: iphone, javascript, touch

```
! function (e) {
  function t() {
    this.removeEventListener("touchmove", n), this.removeEventListener("touchend", t), c = !1
  }

  function n(n) {
    if (e.detectSwipe.preventDefault && n.preventDefault(), c) {
      var i, s = n.touches[0].pageX,
        u = n.touches[0].pageY,
        r = o - s,
        a = 0; //h - u;
      Math.abs(r) >= e.detectSwipe.threshold ? i = r > 0 ? "left" : "right" : Math.abs(a) >= e.detectSwipe.threshold && (i = a > 0 ? "down" : "up"), i && (t.call(this), e(this).trigger("swipe", i).trigger("swipe" + i))
    }
  }

  function i(e) {
    1 == e.touches.length && (o = e.touches[0].pageX, h = e.touches[0].pageY, c = !0, this.addEventListener("touchmove", n, !1), this.addEventListener("touchend", t, !1))
  }

  function s() {
    this.addEventListener("touchstart", i, !1)
  }
  e.detectSwipe = {
    version: "2.1.1",
    enabled: "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement,
    preventDefault: !0,
    threshold: 20
  };
  var o, h, c = !1;
  e.event.special.swipe = {
    setup: s
  }, e.each(["left", "up", "down", "right"], function () {
    e.event.special["swipe" + this] = {
      setup: function () {
        e(this).on("swipe", e.noop)
      }
    }
  })
}(jQuery);
```

In iPhone 6 Safari, when clicking on image in a web page, a popup photo gallery appears.  When swiping up/down the background web page scrolls up/down.  How do I disable swipe up/down in the above javascript code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: According to that site's Help Center: *Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here.* @Moab

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator  ok, so where does it belong?

Comment: One of the dev sites.

Comment: @Moab This is off-topic on Apple.SE since we don't allow code-level programming questions. OP reposted their question there and it is now closed.

Comment: @music3myear - how do I find what the dev sites are?